# Rearranging cells Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to rearrange a large data set and am thinking VBA is the best, most effective method to do this.

I have a data set similar to this structure:

[image: input]

and with this data, I'm trying to get this output:

[image: output]

Has anyone written anything to do this sort of thing? I'd be most grateful for any suggestions or advise on where to go with this.

Many thanks,

Comment: The method is called unpivot.

Comment: Where does Ted come from? He cannot be found in the first image.

Comment: @user11060139 it’s just a standard names that goes with each company. Easily insert that column manually.

Answer (score 2):

## Transpose Data (Rearrange)

Adjust the values in the constants section to fit your needs.

### Links

[Workbook Download (Dropbox)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v5ukk7affe3xu0e/rearranging-cells-excel-vba_54727780.xls?dl=0)

### Images

**Source** (Sheet1)

[image]

**Target 1** (Sheet2)

[image]

**Target 2** (Sheet3)

[image]

`ID` is not gonna happen because, like `Ted` in the previous version, it is nowhere to be found.

### Version 1

```
Sub TransposeData1()

    ' Source
    Const cSource As String = "Sheet1"  ' Worksheet Name
    Const cFR As Long = 2               ' First Row Number
    Const cFRC As Variant = "A"         ' First-Row Column Letter/Number
    Const cRep As String = "B"          ' Repeat Columns Range Address
    Const cUni As String = "C:G"        ' Unique Columns Range Address

    ' Target
    Const cTarget As String = "Sheet2"  ' Worksheet Name
    Const cHeaders As String = "IDDiff,Supervisor,Primary,Secondary"
    Const cSupervisor As String = "Ted" ' Supervisor
    Const cFCell As String = "A1"       ' First Cell Range Address

    ' Source
    Dim rng As Range      ' First-Row Column Last Used Cell Range
    Dim vntR As Variant   ' Repeat Array
    Dim vntU As Variant   ' Unique Array
    Dim NoR As Long       ' Number of Records

    ' Target
    Dim vntH As Variant   ' Header Array
    Dim vntT As Variant   ' Target Array
    Dim CUR As Long       ' Current Column
    Dim i As Long         ' Target Array Row Counter
    Dim j As Long         ' Target/Repeat Array Column Counter
    Dim k As Long         ' Repeat/Unique Array Row Counter
    Dim m As Long         ' Unique Array Column Counter

    ' Speed up.
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    On Error GoTo ProcedureExit

    ' In Source Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSource).Columns(cFRC)
        ' In First-Row Column
        With .Columns(cFRC)
            ' Calculate First-Row Column Last Used Cell Range.
            Set rng = .Find("*", , xlFormulas, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
            ' Check if no data in First-Row Column.
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "No data in column '" _
                        & Split(.Cells(1).Address, "$")(1) & "'."
                GoTo ProcedureExit
            End If
            ' Calculate Number of Records needed to calculate Repeat Range
            ' and Unique Range.
            NoR = rng.Row - cFR + 1
        End With
        ' In Repeat Columns
        With .Columns(cRep)
            ' Copy calculated Repeat Range to Repeat Array.
            vntR = .Cells(1).Offset(cFR - 1).Resize(NoR, .Columns.Count)
        End With
        ' In Unique Columns
        With .Columns(cUni)
            ' Copy calculated Unique Range to Unique Array.
            vntU = .Cells(1).Offset(cFR - 1).Resize(NoR, .Columns.Count)
        End With
    End With

    ' In Arrays

    ' Resize Target Array:
    '   Rows
    '     1                     - for Headers.
    '     NoR * Ubound(vntU, 2) - for data.
    '   Columns
    '     1               - for IDs.
    '     1               - for Supervisor.
    '     UBound(vntR, 2) - for Repeat Array Columns.
    '     1               - for unique values.
    ReDim vntT(1 To 1 + NoR * UBound(vntU, 2), _
            1 To 1 + 1 + UBound(vntR, 2) + 1)

    ' Headers to Header Array
    vntH = Split(cHeaders, ",")

    ' Header Array to Target Array
    For j = 1 To UBound(vntT, 2)
        vntT(1, j) = Trim(vntH(j - 1))
    Next

    ' IDs to Target Array
    CUR = CUR + 1 ' Calculate Current Column in Target Array.
    For i = 2 To UBound(vntT)
        vntT(i, CUR) = i - 1
    Next

    ' Supervisor to Target Array
    CUR = CUR + 1 ' Calculate Current Column in Target Array.
    For i = 2 To UBound(vntT)
        vntT(i, CUR) = cSupervisor
    Next

    ' Repeat Array to Target Array
    CUR = CUR + 1 ' Calculate Current Column in Target Array.
    i = 1 ' First row of Target Array contains Headers.
    ' Task: Write values of current rows (k) in columns (j) in Repeat Array
    ' to current rows (i) in columns (j + CUR - 1) of Target Array as many
    ' times as there are columns (m) in Unique Array.
    For k = 1 To UBound(vntR) ' Rows of Repeat Array
        For m = 1 To UBound(vntU, 2) ' Columns of Unique Array
            i = i + 1 ' Count current row of Target Array.
            For j = 1 To UBound(vntR, 2) ' Columns of Repeat Array
                ' Write value of current record in Repeat Array
                ' to current record of Target Array.
                vntT(i, j + CUR - 1) = vntR(k, j)
            Next
        Next
    Next

    ' Unique Array to Target Array
    CUR = CUR + UBound(vntR, 2) ' Calculate Current Column in Target Array.
    i = 1 ' First row of Target Array contains Headers.
    ' Task: Write values of current row (k) and current column (m) of Unique
    ' Array each to the next row (i) in current column (CUR) of Target Array.
    For k = 1 To UBound(vntU) ' Rows of Unique Array
        For m = 1 To UBound(vntU, 2) ' Columns of Unique Array
            i = i + 1 ' Count current row of Target Array.
            ' Write value of current record in Unique Array
            ' to current record of Target Array.
            vntT(i, CUR) = vntU(k, m)
        Next
    Next

    ' In Target Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cTarget).Range(cFCell)
        ' Clear contents of Target Range and the range below it.
        .Resize(.Parent.Rows.Count - .Parent.Range(cFCell).Row + 1, _
                UBound(vntT, 2)).ClearContents
        ' Copy Target Array to Target Range.
        .Resize(UBound(vntT), UBound(vntT, 2)) = vntT
    End With

ProcedureExit:

    ' Speed down.
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

### Version 2

```
Sub TransposeData2()

    ' Source
    Const cSource As String = "Sheet1"  ' Worksheet Name
    Const cFR As Long = 2               ' First Row Number
    Const cFRC As Variant = "A"         ' First-Row Column Letter/Number
    Const cRep As String = "A:B"        ' Repeat Columns Range Address
    Const cUni As String = "C:G"        ' Unique Columns Range Address
    Const cUH As Long = 1               ' Unique Header Row Number

    ' Target
    Const cTarget As String = "Sheet3"  ' Worksheet Name
    Const cHeaders As String = "ID,Primary,Secondary,Relationship"
    Const cFCell As String = "A1"       ' First Cell Range Address

    ' Source
    Dim rng As Range      ' First-Row Column Last Used Cell Range
    Dim vntR As Variant   ' Repeat Array
    Dim vntU As Variant   ' Unique Array
    Dim NoR As Long       ' Number of Records

    ' Target
    Dim vntH As Variant   ' Header Array
    Dim vntT As Variant   ' Target Array
    Dim vntUH As Variant  ' Unique Header Array
    Dim CUR As Long       ' Current Column
    Dim i As Long         ' Target Array Row Counter
    Dim j As Long         ' Target/Repeat Array Column Counter
    Dim k As Long         ' Repeat/Unique Array Row Counter
    Dim m As Long         ' Unique/Unique Header Array Column Counter

    ' Speed up.
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    On Error GoTo ProcedureExit

    ' In Source Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSource).Columns(cFRC)
        ' In First-Row Column
        With .Columns(cFRC)
            ' Calculate First-Row Column Last Used Cell Range.
            Set rng = .Find("*", , xlFormulas, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
            ' Check if no data in First-Row Column.
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "No data in column '" _
                        & Split(.Cells(1).Address, "$")(1) & "'."
                GoTo ProcedureExit
            End If
            ' Calculate Number of Records needed to calculate Repeat Range
            ' and Unique Range.
            NoR = rng.Row - cFR + 1
        End With
        ' In Repeat Columns
        With .Columns(cRep)
            ' Copy calculated Repeat Range to Repeat Array.
            vntR = .Cells(1).Offset(cFR - 1).Resize(NoR, .Columns.Count)
        End With
        ' In Unique Columns
        With .Columns(cUni)
            ' Copy calculated Unique Range to Unique Array.
            vntU = .Cells(1).Offset(cFR - 1).Resize(NoR, .Columns.Count)
            ' Copy calculated Unique Header Range to Unique Header Array.
            vntUH = .Cells(1).Offset(cUH - 1).Resize(, .Columns.Count)
        End With
    End With

    ' In Arrays

    ' Resize Target Array:
    '   Rows
    '     1                     - for Headers.
    '     NoR * Ubound(vntU, 2) - for data.
    '   Columns
    '     UBound(vntR, 2) - for Repeat Array Columns.
    '     1               - for unique values.
    '     1               - for Unique Header Row.
    ReDim vntT(1 To 1 + NoR * UBound(vntU, 2), _
            1 To UBound(vntR, 2) + 1 + 1)

    ' Write Headers to Header Array.
    vntH = Split(cHeaders, ",")
    ' Write Headers to Target Array.
    For j = 1 To UBound(vntT, 2)
        vntT(1, j) = Trim(vntH(j - 1))
    Next

    ' Repeat Array to Target Array
    CUR = CUR + 1 ' Calculate Current Column in Target Array.
    i = 1 ' First row of Target Array contains Headers.
    ' Task: Write values of current rows (k) in columns (j) in Repeat Array
    ' to current rows (i) in columns (j + CUR - 1) of Target Array as many
    ' times as there are columns (m) in Unique Array.
    For k = 1 To UBound(vntR) ' Rows of Repeat Array
        For m = 1 To UBound(vntU, 2) ' Columns of Unique Array
            i = i + 1 ' Count current row of Target Array.
            For j = 1 To UBound(vntR, 2) ' Columns of Repeat Array
                ' Write value of current record in Repeat Array
                ' to current record of Target Array.
                vntT(i, j + CUR - 1) = vntR(k, j)
            Next
        Next
    Next

    ' Unique Array to Target Array
    CUR = CUR + UBound(vntR, 2) ' Calculate Current Column in Target Array.
    i = 1 ' First row of Target Array contains Headers.
    ' Task: Write values of current row (k) and current column (m) of Unique
    ' Array each to the next row (i) in current column (CUR) of Target Array.
    For k = 1 To UBound(vntU) ' Rows of Unique Array
        For m = 1 To UBound(vntU, 2) ' Columns of Unique Array
            i = i + 1 ' Count current row of Target Array.
            ' Write value of current record in Unique Array
            ' to current record of Target Array.
            vntT(i, CUR) = vntU(k, m)
        Next
    Next

    ' Unique Header Array to Target Array
    CUR = CUR + 1 ' Calculate Current Column in Target Array.
    i = 1 ' First row of Target Array contains Headers.
    ' Task: Write values of current column (m) of Unique Header Array each
    ' to the next row (i) in current column (CUR) of Target Array as many
    ' times as there are rows(k) in Unique Array.
    For k = 1 To UBound(vntU) ' Rows of Unique Array
        For m = 1 To UBound(vntUH, 2) ' Columns of Unique Header Array
            i = i + 1 ' Count current row of Target Array.
            ' Write value of current record in Unique Array
            ' to current record of Target Array.
            vntT(i, CUR) = vntUH(1, m)
        Next
    Next

    ' In Target Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cTarget).Range(cFCell)
        ' Clear contents of Target Range and the range below it.
        .Resize(.Parent.Rows.Count - .Parent.Range(cFCell).Row + 1, _
                UBound(vntT, 2)).ClearContents
        ' Copy Target Array to Target Range.
        .Resize(UBound(vntT), UBound(vntT, 2)) = vntT
    End With

ProcedureExit:

    ' Speed down.
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this - It's very helpful. I notice the ID is incrementing 1,2,3,4 - how can I get this to use whatever number is in the ID column instead? Also, is there some way we can add the column headers Manager, Manager2 etc next to the respective entry? So, for example, in my table Wendy would have Manger next to it and Evan would have Manager2 for Company1 Ltd?
Sincere thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: You should think about it for a while and then create the exact result and post the image or a link to the workbook. Ha,ha,ha. I see Ted did get a boot. Take your time and create a final solution. I'll be back in 20 hours or so.

Comment: Hi VBasic2008. Thank you so much for this - you've got me the desired result. I am so sorry for my misleading initial post that didn't really help you. You have achieved my desired result and I am ever so grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop through the names, and output them in a column.
Something like the following maybe:

```
Option Explicit
Sub sort()
Dim rArea As Range, lRow As Long, oCN As Long, outCol As String, cell As Range
'Set this to the range of names
Set rArea = ActiveSheet.Range("C2:G4")
'Set this to output
outCol = "J"

oCN = Columns(outCol).Column
For Each cell In rArea
    lRow = ActiveSheet.Range(outCol & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Update last row in output column
    Cells(lRow + 1, oCN).Value = cell.Value                                 'Print Name
    Cells(lRow + 1, oCN - 1).Value = Cells(cell.Row, 2).Value               'Print Company
Next cell
End Sub
```

I made some last minute changes for dynamics. But compare with the picture, and you should be able to figure out what I'm doing.

[image]

I don't see the point to adding the other rows with a macro, but you can do that as well obviously.